# Flutter widget is visible to user

Tags: flutter

I'm experimenting with masking select types of widgets in app screenshots. It works relatively well based on global positioning, but there's an issue when apps overlay widgets one on top of another, such as here with a menu that's actually always visible, but a "page" slides over it when it's not "open": https://github.com/mitesh77/Best-Flutter-UI-Templates

See animated use of this scenario in the following gif, and the screenshots captured with the obscured parts grayed out, first with the menu open, the second with the menu closed but still the hidden widgets are grayed out.

[image: How widgets overlay one another]

[image: a]

[image: b]

Then when I'm traversing the widget tree to determine widgets positions to obscure, the menu items are also encountered.

Is there any way to determine widgets that are actually visible to the user? Or is there another way I could go at this that would allow me to filter out widgets that I don't want to screenshot?

I cannot change app code, the screenshot+obscure logic is meant to live in a library so I don't really have a way to influence how the app that uses it is built.

Comment: Didn't try it, but does visibily detector may help you? https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector

Comment: I cannot change app code, the screenshot+obscure logic is meant to live in a library so I don't really have a way to influence how the app that uses it is built. Therefore, I don't think visibility detector works in this case.